# Number of movements Hanoi Haskell

Tags: haskell, towers-of-hanoi

I wanna know how i could write the code in haskell for knowing how **many movements**  for a number n of "discs" and 3 sticks ( A , B , C)

Base case ( N=1): Movement A --> C   so 1 movement

Inductive case ( N = M+1 ) : I move M discs "A" ---> "C" and ,I move 1 disc "A" ---> "B" and finally I move M discs from "C" to "B".  I thought that the de code could be this:

```
numMoveHanoi 0 = 0 
numMoveHanoi 1 = 1 
numMoveHanoi n = m+1 + numMoveHanoi m 
                 where m = n-1
```

Unfortunately this only works for the case numMoveHanoi 2 .Other cases, the result is wrong.  I don't know where my recursion definition is wrong .

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask someone to write code for you, you need to show that you have a basic understanding of the problem and show an attempted solution.  This is a place for help solving a problem, not a place to get your problem solved for you.

Comment: I'm sorry , I didnt know that I must write my code . I'm going to put it ( I had written before asking :P ). Sorry again for the confusion

Answer (score 5):

Well, just try lining up your English with your Haskell.

```
numMoveHanoi {- Base case ( N=1) -} 1
    = {- Movement A --> C so 1 movement -} 1
numMoveHanoi {- Inductive case -} n
    = {- I move M discs "A" ---> "C" -} m
    + {- I move 1 disc "A" ---> "B" -} 1
    + {- I move M discs from "C" to "B" -} numMoveHanoi m
    where {- ( N = M+1 ) -} m = n-1
```

Now, compare the English in the first and third clauses of `numMoveHanoi`. Then compare the Haskell in the first and third clauses of `numMoveHanoi`.

(And as an exercise: compare the English in the second and third clauses. Then compare the Haskell in the second and third clauses. Is this an instance of the same bug? Why or why not?)

Answer (score 0):

Think about the recursive solution for the tower of hanoi: to solve a tower with n discs, move the top n-1 discs to a spare platform (numMoveHanoi (n-1)), move the nth disc (1), and move the top n-1 discs on top of the nth dics (numMoveHanoi (n-1)). Then your general case:

```
numMovesHanoi n = numMoveHanoi (n-1) + 1 + numMoveHanoi (n-1)
{- or numMovesHanoi n = 2 * numMoveHanoi (n-1) + 1 -}
```